# Como enviar um formulario sem utilizar um botão

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom queria quando o usuário clica-se fora da do input o formulario fosse enviado, e também que a página não recarregue

meu index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="formulario">
        <button onclick="carregaFormulario()">Gera formulario</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function carregaFormulario() {
            let divConteudo = document.getElementById('formulario')
            let formulario = document.createElement('form')
            let input = document.createElement('input')

            input.name = 'nome'
            formulario.appendChild(input)
            formulario.method = 'post'
            formulario.action = '#'
            input.onblur = () =>{
                //submeter o formulario
                console.log('Estou aqui')
            }

            divConteudo.appendChild(formulario)
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Thor, para a parte que você deseja que a página não recarreguem vale à pena aprofundar seus conhecimentos com *Ajax* ou algum outro framework que o implementa.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o Ajax para enviar o formulário sem recarregar a página.

```js
    $.ajax({
      "type":"post",
      "url":"suaurlaqui",
      "data": "os dados no formato JSON",
      "success": function(data){
           //Implementa alguma coisa se sucesso
      },
      "error": function (erro){
           //Implementa alguma coisa se erro
       }
    })
```

Neste link você tem acesso completo a API do Ajax no jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/